# Store the result of LoadInst in an Int

Tags: load, int, llvm, instructions

When we create a LoadInst in LLVM IR, the result is a pointer to the value. If I am reading the value of a `int` variable called `x` using `LoadInst` in LLVM IR, the result I get is another the pointer to that value. How to store the result in an `int`?

Answer (score 0):

LLVM IR has neither variables not an `int` type. But reading from an `int x` variable in a C-like language will typically be translated to a *load* instruction in LLVM IR, and I'm guessing this is what you're asking about.

The answer is that creating *any* LLVM instruction nets you a `Value*` (or a pointer to subtype of `Value`). The question is, what the type of that value is. For a *load* instruction, if its operand is of type `i32*`, the load itself will be of type `i32` - so the load does indeed get the actual value out of the pointer.

If you want to then put the integer under some other address - storing it somewhere else - you should use a *store* instruction.